# allocating memory to pointer of typedef

Tags: c, pointers, memory, malloc, typedef

I'm hiding a pointer with the *typedef* and I'm trying to make an array of it. my structure is:

```
typedef struct s {
    int y;
    int x;
    int value;
} s;

typedef s *t;
```

and the main:

```
int main()
{
    t *var;
    int arg;
    var = malloc(sizeof(t*));
    arg = 40;
    for (int x = 0; x < arg; x++)
    {
        var[x] = malloc(sizeof(t));
        var[x]->x = -1;
        var[x]->y = -1;
        var[x]->value = 0;
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < arg; x++)
    {
        printf("|%d| ",var[x]->value);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

sometime it just goes to segmentation fault and sometimes the value is just dirty, but it still means that it did not allocated the memory as intented. what am I missing? I'm just trying to make an array of type *t* with *arg* length which must be a variable

Comment: *I'm hiding a pointer with the typedef*. Advice: Don't do that. It just obscures the code and makes it harder for everyone to understand. That may even be contributing to your current problem. The  first `malloc` should use `sizeof(t * arg)` or better still `sizeof(*var * arg)`. And move `arg=40` to be above that.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm hiding a pointer with the typedef

This very bad practice is the root of all your bugs. Simply *don't* hide pointers behind typedef.

Because now you have a `t* var` which is actually a `s**`. Then you call `var = malloc(sizeof(t*));` which is completely wrong, because you allocate room for a `s**`.

You should have allocated room for `40 * sizeof(s*)` or otherwise `var[x]` will seg fault.

And then typedef or not, this is not a 2D array but a segmented look-up table, which adds extra complexity and slower code, for absolutely nothing gained. See [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays). But it doesn't even look like you need a 2D array, so what's all of that coming from?

With all of this in mind, lets go with the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and rewrite the code from scratch:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
  int y;
  int x;
  int value;
} s;

int main (void)
{
  int arg = 40;
  s* var = malloc(arg * sizeof(*var));

  for (int i = 0; i < arg; i++)
  {
    var[i].x = -1;
    var[i].y = -1;
    var[i].value = 0;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < arg; i++)
  {
    printf("|%d| ",var[i].value);
  }

  free(var);
  return 0;
}
```

A 2D version would use `s (*var)[y] = malloc( sizeof(s[x][y]) );` instead.